# Start windows service on remote machine using NSIS script

Tags: windows-services, remote-desktop, nsis

Can I start a service on remote machine using NSIS script. I know we can use:

```
sc \\machine start servicename
```

through DOS prompt. But can we do the same in NSIS? Can SimpleSC be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exec`.

```
ExecWait 'net start $servicename'
```

**Edit:** Oh, you meant starting the service on the remote machine...well:

```
ExecWait 'sc \\machine start servicename'
```